# Отправка формы с картинкой.AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Оправляю форму с картинкой. Если без нее,то все отправляется и в базу идет сохранение. Но с картинкой не могу реализовать. Вот куски кода.

```
// POST: api/Products
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.Id }, product);
    }
```

Добавить товар

```
                <form name="addProduct" data-ng-show="addMode" style="width:600px;margin:0px auto;">
                    <div class=" form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Имя товара:</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Введите название товара" data-ng-model="newproduct.Name" required />
                        </div>
                        <label for="description" class="control-label">Описание</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Введите описание товара" data-ng-model="newproduct.Description" required />
                        </div>
                        <label for="image" class="control-label">Фото</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"  required />

                        </div>
                        <label for="price" class="control-label">Цена</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Введите цену товара" data-ng-model="newproduct.Price" required />
                        </div>
                        <label for="category" class="control-label">Категория:</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Введите категорию товара" data-ng-model="newproduct.Category.Name" required />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add" data-ng-click="add()" data-ng-disabled="!addProduct.$valid" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </form>

(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('productController', ['$scope', '$http', productController]);

   function productController($scope, $http) {

    //declare variable for mainain ajax load and entry or edit mode
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.addMode = false;
    $scope.addModeCategory = false; // my

    //get all product information
    $http.get('/api/Products/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
        $scope.loading = false;
    });

    //by pressing toggleEdit button ng-click in html, this method will be hit
    $scope.toggleEdit = function () {
        this.product.editMode = !this.product.editMode;
    };

    $scope.toggleAddCategory = function () {  //my
        $scope.addModeCategory = !$scope.addModeCategory;
    };

    //by pressing toggleAdd button ng-click in html, this method will be hit
    $scope.toggleAdd = function () {
        $scope.addMode = !$scope.addMode;
    };

    //Добавление товара
    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.post('/api/Products/', this.newproduct).success(function (data) {
            alert("Товар добавлен!");
            $scope.addMode = false;
            $scope.products.push(data);
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "Произошла ошибка при добавлении товара!" + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };
```

как изменить  $scope.add и контроллер api/Products чтобы сохранить картинку в папке а в базу записать ее путь?

Comment: Может, у вас опечатка. Вы используете `this.newproduct`. Думаю, в контексте выполнения функции `$scope.add` - `this` является `window`. Соответственно, свойства `newproduct`  в  `window` нет, поскольку он находится в `$scope`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, функция выполняется как метод $scope, поэтому _this_ внутри указывает на `$scope`. Здесь проблема в том, что картинка просто никак не собирается и соответственно не отправляется на сервер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки файлов мы используем следующую небольшую библиотеку [ngFileUpload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Пользоваться ей просто.

Пример использования.

```
<input nice-name="Прикрепляемый документ" name="uplURL" ng-model="upl.URL" placeholder="Название файла" class="form-control" required readonly>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button ngf-select 
                    ngf-change="forUpload($files,upl,$rejectedFiles)"
                    ngf-accept="'image/*,application/pdf'"
                    ngf-min-size="4096"
                    ngf-max-size="65536">Обзор</button>
        </span>
```

---

Пример функции `forUpload`.

```
$scope.forUpload=function(files,upl,rejected){
        if(angular.isDefined(files[0])){
            upl.URL=files[0].name;
            upl.FILE=files[0];
            upl.MIME_TYPE=files[0].type;
        }
        if(angular.isDefined(rejected[0]))
            upl.rejected=rejected[0];
    }
```